# What is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb A^n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It's well known that the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^n$ is $\operatorname{PGL}_{n+1}$, the projective general linear group.  What is the automorphism group of $\mathbb A^n$?  It includes $\operatorname{GL}_n$,  but surely there are more automorphisms of affine space than those given by invertible matrices.

Comment: It is $G=Aut(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/k)$ which is complicated (not an algebraic group) since replacing $x_1$ by $x_1+f(x_2\ldots,x_n)$ is an automorphism